# Class Inside a Class in C++: Is that heavy?

Tags: c++, class, overhead

Suppose I do something like:

```
class A
{
public:
    class B
    {
    public:
         void SomeFunction1() const;
         using atype = A;
    };

    using btype = B;
    void SomeFunction2() const;

private:
    B b;
};
```

Then I create an instance of class A and copy it:

```
A a;
A acopy = a;
```

Does that make the class A heavy, what I mean is, what happens in the background? I would hope that C++ doesn't really literally "consider" the definition of class B everytime I declare an instance of class A, I thin what happens in the background is that class B will be treated as a new definition under a namespace named A, so A::B is defined. My question is does defining a class inside a class (B inside A) create any overhead when declaring or copying the class A, or it's treated exactly as if B is defined outside?

Thank you everyone :)

Comment: if `class B` is public, then it's worth asking yourself why you need it confined within the "namespace" defined by `class A`.

Comment: I have a clear reason why :), in my case class B only exists if class A exists, think of B as Specification (E.g. Inputs Map) of class A. I am pretty sure even if I am wrong desigining  this, this is a more generic question, unless you are saying I should always avoid this? Coming back to my question, should I avoid doing this? Is it heavy?

Comment: You are confusing classes with objects.  Putting a class definition inside of another is just changing how the inner class is *named*.  That's all.

If class B were defined outside of class A and nothing else was changed (i.e. if every instance of class A still contained an instance of class B) there would be zero difference in the "heaviness" of the objects

Comment: It seems (from your basic structure shown) that it's arbitrary which class is inside which if they have this interdependency. Why not have them separate classes within a single `namespace`. It might be clearer although as Joe points out, no impact on "heaviness".

Comment: @Joe Thanks you, I think it's clear now that defining a class inside a class adds zero overhead (only member variables and functions defined inside the class are adding overhead).

Comment: @lurker Thank you Lurker, I will have many classes of type A :) inheriting from a base class, I can't everytime create a namespace, I feel you don't like creating a class inside a class, I see what you mean, that it does not add anything as it's public, but I think it compacts things together and readers of the code understand more that B only exists under the context of A. But please if you have more reasons why I shouldn't, more than welcome to learn :)

Comment: It's not that I don't like creating a class within a class. I'm just exploring if, in this case, it makes logical sense from a clarity and namespace definition perspective. It has its place, but I would not do it arbitrarily and have it imply something that is not intended. It does imply, as you have written it, that `class B` is somehow "contained in" or is "owned by" or is "part of" `class A` in some logical sense. But I don't know your big picture, so I reckon that is up to you. :) Maybe it isn't arbitrary as it appeared to me in the simple example.

Comment: Thank you again for taking time to answer :) Yeah in my case really B is under linked to A and only exists under the context of A being existing. I think that's one of the cases where I should declare it inside :). Thanks everyone, please in the meantime add answers if you have new thoughs on this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both possibilities (B as nested class and B as external class) will yield exactly the same performance.

In fact, the compiler will generate the same assembly code in both cases.

**B as external class:**

https://godbolt.org/z/7voYGd6Mf

**B as nested class:**

https://godbolt.org/z/731dPdrqo

B is a member of A. Hence it resides in A's memory layout and B's constructor will be called every time you constructor/copy A.
The introduced overhead depends on B implementation, but it will be identical in both cases (B nested and external class),

Answer (score 0):

My own opinion is:

- It's heavy to read, even with source code folding.
- It's often useless: `B` class could be fully merged with `A` class most of the time.
- Even if `B` if required by `A`, and *never ever* used elsewhere, it can be defined out of `A`. Constructors are your friends to "force" some associations - delete the default constructor, for example.
- Inside or outside `A`, it doesn't change anything regarding deep copy.
- If you need to expose `B` directly through `A`, it's a design flaw - move these functions from `B` to `A` instead.

So I really don't see, apart "sparing" a header file, what you can "gain" by declaring a class within a class...

For my part, I would prefer:

- Use the [PIMPL idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) to "hide" `B`, if it isn't required publicly.
- Move everything that needs to be exposed publicly in `A` either permanently (move the source code), or use wrappers to the PIMPL object.
- If you need to replace/share a `B` instance, change the `unique_ptr` for the PIMPL object to a `shared_ptr` instead. Take care of deep copy.

It's usually WAY more efficient, hides perfectly the `B` code if required (don't even need to export it from a DLL, for example), you won't recompile `B` at all when changing `A` and you can change how `B` work without even breaking your `A` API.

Comment: This is an opinion, and fails to answer the question.

Comment: PIMPL idiom introduces the need to access the heap to allocate and free the implementation object, which is (often unnecessary) additional runtime overhead and precludes the class from being usable in some contexts (eg in a real-time thread)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Not necessary. You can have a reference attribute member (here, `B& pB;`) constructed directly in `A` constructor, without dynamic allocation. In a realtime thread, anyway, you rarely build objects, better to preallocate everything needed. But it's somewhat a detail anyway, it won't be better with a `B` class declared within the `A` class. Still need to access `B` stuff from `A`, so runtime overhead is already there.

Comment: @Wisblade in that scenario, where would the `B` object referenced by `pB` be stored, and how would its lifetime be managed?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Lifetime of `B` is the same as `A`. `pB` is a reference, usually through a `unique_ptr`, so it's handled like all RAII-compliant objects: when its "parent" is destroyed, it's destroyed with it... Or did I missed what you wanted to point out?

Comment: @Wisblade maybe I'm misunderstanding, but if `B` is a member-variable of `A`, then it's not PIMPL idiom anymore... OTOH if `B` is not a member-variable of `A`, then you need some mechanism for creating `B` and destroying `B` at the appropriate times (i.e. when its `A` owner is created and destroyed).  Traditional PIMPL would do that inside `A`'s constructor and destructor using the heap, but you seem to suggest another mechanism that doesn't require the heap, and I'm curious what that is.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner As long as `B` implementation and structure isn't visible, it's still PIMPL, whatever method you use (from ugly `void*` passed to `reinterpret_cast` to proper smart pointers). Like singleton, there is several methods to realize that, with specific pros and cons for each. Honestly, I don't use that reference trick so often (can't change it at runtime if `const`-ed). My common PIMPL use case is with a `shared_ptr<B*>` most of the time, preallocated, so I never searched WHERE the instance was stored (within `A`? On stack? Data segment?) when using references.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is a compiled language. We generally assume that the computers used to compile C++ source code are powerful enough. Compilers may reasonable use Gigabytes in the process of compiling an executable.

So when we say that something is "heavy", we usually mean that it's heavy at runtime. The runtime environment for a C++ program may well be a coffee maker or a fridge.

Things like name lookup in nested scopes are pure compile-time actions, and do not have any runtime impact. And modern compilers are smart enough to inline the default methods here, so there's no runtime overhead in calling members.

Answer (score 0):

So I am the one asking the question, I have tested what @david dragilev implemented on Google Benchmark. Results attached, indeed the difference is very small. I can't say the outside version is faster but it theoritically (based on the numbers) is.

Results: https://quick-bench.com/q/sgwCs8kHfePvAaFeLe03uqmCsIo

Comment: In addition to providing the link to the quick-bench, you should provide a part of the code that was modified or changed so that people can refer to it here.